# Is there fsync but with path parameter

Tags: c, linux

Is there linux system call similar to fsync but uses file path instead of file descriptor?
I modify file modification time using utime, the file is in USB, I need to make sure the time is flushed to usb after setting utime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't.

To do so you need to

1. `open()` the file
2. call `fsync()` on the fd returned by 1.
3. `close()` the fd returned by 1.
4. `open()` the containing directory
5. call `fsync()` on the fd returned by 4.
6. `close()` the fd returned by 4.

As you are after updating the file's meta-data the steps 4 to 6 **are** necessary to get the directory's **entries** (which carry the file's meta data) to disk.

As per [*Throwback1986*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74774/throwback1986)'s comment please note that this is **not** working  recursivly in any way.

Comment: And note that calling fsync on the dir *does not* recursively synch the files and/or dirs within the synched dir

Comment: I need to call utime after writing to the file in usb, when should I call utime so that the time modification is sync to the usb.
I think I can use futimes instead of utime.
And why do I need to open the containing directory?

Comment: @dragon135: Why would you want to set the modification timestamp explcitly, as this would be done implicitly by writing to the file? I mentioned in my answer why the containing direcorey needs to be fsync'ed. I updated my answer to be more explicit on this.

Comment: I need to copy the access and modification time from another file. It is like copying file, so need to copy the time attribute.

Comment: Does it mean that the date/metadata file information is carried by the containing folder? I don't know about this before.

Comment: @dragon135: Not necessarily but the direcory entry is the instance displaying it to the user, so if it not had been written to disk yet, the file might be around carrying all its data, but the directory simply hasn't been updated with this new entry yet.

Comment: I have tried this, but still there is case the usb folder becomes corrupt when plugout 3seconds after the command completes:
-1. create dir 'A' in USB, fsync and close dir 'A'
-2. create file 'f' inside 'A'
-3. write data, fsync and close 'f'
-4. change timestamp using futimes and then fsync and close 'f'
-5. fsync and close dir 'A'
--> plugout USB after 3 seconds, then when enter folder 'A' again there is error opening the directory (corrupted).
It seems there is no way to guarantee the disc sync operation is finished after calling fync.

Comment: @dragon135: I supect you won't get around unmounting the usb-folder.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about this "unmounting usb folder"?

Comment: @dragon135: Please this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20709332/694576 on your other question.

Comment: @alk back to your answer, it is not clear do I need to recursively fsync all of the upper directory? for example: path /A/B/C/. If I update file/directory inside C, do I need to fsync C then B then A?

Comment: @dragon135: In case one of such directories has been touched and/or your want their time-stamps to be updated as well: yes each one you are interested in needs by fsync'ed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet of code I lifted from some of my utility routines in a POSIX-like system.   The code includes the synching helper function, as well as the recursive caller.  It may not compile "out of the box" since it was from a specialized system, but it's close enough to get you on the right track.

```
  static int sync_path(const char *path)
        {
        int fd = 0;
        int ret = 0;


        if (path == NULL)
          {
            printf("Invalid path (NULL)");
            return -1;
        }

        fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
        if (fd < 0)
          {
        printf("Failed to open dir [%d:%s] (%s)",
               errno, strerror(errno), path);
        return errno;
          }

        ret = fsync(fd);
        if (ret < 0)
          {

        printf("Failed to sync dir [%d:%s] (%s)",
              errno, strerror(errno), path);

            close(fd);
        return errno;
        }

        ret = close(fd);
        if (ret < 0)
          {
        printf("Failed to close dir [%d:%s] (%s)",
                        errno, strerror(errno), path);

            return errno;
        }

        return 0;
    }


    int sync_tree(const char *path)
    {
        static size_t depth = 0;

        struct dirent *entry = NULL;

        DIR *dir = NULL;

        const char *p = NULL;

        int ret = 0;


        if (path == NULL)
        {
                printf("Invalid path (NULL)");
            return -1;
        }

        depth++;
        if (depth > MAX_RECURSION_DEPTH)
        {
                printf("Recursion limit reached [%d]",
                        MAX_RECURSION_DEPTH);
            return -1;
        }

        ret = chdir(path);
        if (ret)
        {
          printf("Unable to chdir [%d:%s] (%s)",
             errno, strerror(errno), path);

          return errno;
        }

        // Operate on the current dir (after the chdir above)
        dir = opendir("./");
        if (dir == NULL)
          {
        printf("Unable to open dir [%d:%s] (%s)",
               errno, strerror(errno), path);
        return errno;
        }

        entry = readdir(dir);
        while (entry && (ret == Success))
          {
            p = entry -> d_name;
            if (!p)
          {
                break;
          }

            if (entry -> d_type != DT_DIR)
          {
                ret = sync_path(p);
            }
            else
            {
                // If not dir is not . or .., then process it (depth-first)
                if (strnicmp(p, ".", 1) && strnicmp(p, "..", 2))
                {
              // Recursion here...
              ret = sync_tree(p);
              if (ret)
            {
              // Do nothing - any error message should already be handled
            }
              else
            {
              // Restore current dir
              ret = chdir("../");
              if (ret)
                        {
                  printf("Unable to chdir [%d:%s] (%s)",
                     errno, strerror(errno), "../");

                        }
              else
                        {
                  // All is well...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (ret == 0)
          {
                entry = readdir(dir);
          }
          }
        closedir(dir);

        // Sync this level
        ret = sync_path("./");
        if (ret)
        {
          // Any error message should already be printed, so just return
          return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            // All is well..
        }

        depth--;
        return Success;
    }
```