# How to make sure data integrity after sync/fsync/syncfs to portable device

Tags: c, linux, io

Based on sync manual page, there is no guarantee the disc will flush its cache after calling sync:
"According to the standard specification (e.g., POSIX.1-2001), sync() schedules the writes, but may return before the actual writing is done. However, since version 1.3.20 Linux does actually wait. (This still does not guarantee data integrity: modern disks have large caches.) "

And, in fsync manual, there is no mention about this.

Is there ways to makes sure all writes to disc especially portable device (USB) has been finished after calling sync? I have encountered cases that data and metadata information has not fully written to disc after calling sync/fsync.
I am curious how "Safely remove device" in windows/linux knows that all data has been fully written by the device itself.

Answer (score 2):

> I am curious how "Safely remove device" in windows/linux knows that all data has been fully written by the device itself.

For IXish systems:

Unmount the USB-device's partitions using the [`umount` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/umount.8.html) or the [`umount()` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umount.2.html).

---

Doing

```
blockdev --flushbufs
```

might flush the device's buffer, but does not keep anybody from accessing the devices again and refill buffers.

---

Also there is this kernel interface in the `/proc` file system:

```
/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

which can be used to flush different buffers:

Verbatim from [`https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt)

> [...]
>
> To free dentries and inodes:
>
> ```
>   echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
> ```
>
> [...]

Comment: the drop_caches does not related with device/disc own buffer, it only relates with dirty page in kernel. After call fsync, the buffer in kernel will be transferred to device, I don't care if the dirty page is not freed after that. And the manual about blockdev --flushbufs does not clear, will it ask device to flush it's cache? And it seems that open the block device and then call fsync will make the device write its cache/buffer to the plate?

Answer (score 1):

At least in principle, this is a Linux bug. The specification for sync functions is that the data is fully written to permanent storage; leaving it in a hardware cache is not conforming.

I'm not sure what the correct workaround is, but you can probably `strace` the `hwparm` utility running with the `-F` option (I think that's the right one) to see what it's doing (or read the source, but `strace` is a lot easier).

Comment: is this how "safely remove device" work? it knows that the disc hardware cache is finished (so it is safe to cut device power).